# Passing Python variable as argument to shell script

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I have a python code in which I need to run a shell script by passing arguments. Below is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import sys

filename=sys.argv[1]
subprocess.call(['bash','./shell.sh',filename])
print("Successfully completed")
```

Here I am trying to get an input as an argument while running  `./file.py  (filename)` .But If I try to pass that as an argument to the shell script I am not able exceute the prograam.

Also I tried the code below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import shlex
import sys

filename=sys.argv[1]

subprocess.call(shlex.split('./shell2.sh filename'))
```

For the above code I am getting error like this:

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `filename' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

My script code:

```
file=$1
awk '{
  if($0 ~ /LogType/){
    if(hold ~ /LogType:stderr/){
      print hold;
    }
    hold=$0
  }else{
    if($0 ~ /ERROR/ || $0 ~/WARN/){hold=hold "\n" $0 ": line " NR}else{hold=hold "\n" $0}
  }
}END{
  if(hold ~ /LogType:stderr/){
    print hold
  }
}' $file | sed -n -e 's/^.*LogType:\(stderr\)$/\1/p' \
                 -e 's/^.*Log Upload Time :\(.*\)/\1/p' \
                 -e 's/^.*LogLength:\(.*\)$/\1/p'       \
                 -e 's/^.*\(ERROR\|WARN\).*$/\0/p'
```

How should I pass an input value to a shell script.Kindly help me to solve this issue .Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the error in the first case?

Comment: It didn't give any output .It just hangs

Comment: It works well for me, please share your `shell.sh`.

Comment: Yes I have added to the question

Comment: What does the script do when called directly on the terminal? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: It searches for a pattern in a file and prints the result

Comment: Does the script work if you call it without python?

Comment: Yes it works fine

Comment: Note that ``subprocess.call`` as shown will just have the child write directly to ``stdout``. Are you actually trying to capture the output? Is there some outer process capturing the output, potentially buffering it? Is your output line-separated? Note that your second code snippet implies that Python successfully calls the script, it is the script that fails to provide output or an outer process that fails to consume/show it.

Comment: No there is no other process trying to capture that .  Thank you! I will check my script code again! Thanks a lot!